# JQuery fadeOut operation

Tags: jquery, fadeout

i am having a html structure like

```
<ul>
 <li>   <span class="vcard">
            <a class="underline user-link" href="/users/aruna">Aruna </a>
       </span>
       <div style="display: none;" class="image_hover">
           Student
           <p>
             <a onclick="" href="#">Show additional details</a>
             <a href="#">view</a>
             <p>Employee ID : </p>
             <p>Project Name: </p>
             <p>Project Role : r</p>
             <p>Supervisor Name : </p>
          </p>
     </div>
 </li>
 <li>
      <span class="vcard">
       <a class="underline user-link" href="/users/jasmine">jasmine </a>
      </span>
      <div style="display: none;" class="image_hover">
           Professor
           <p>
             <a onclick="" href="#">Show additional details</a>
             <a href="#">view</a>
             <p>Employee ID : </p>
             <p>Project Name: </p>
             <p>Project Role : r</p>
             <p>Supervisor Name : </p>
          </p>
     </div>
</li>

</ul>
```

I tried a code in jQuery as when we hover on the link inside the span(vcard) the div next to that to fadeIn

And when on hover on other elements of the body other than the link or the div which fades on , the div has to fade Out ..

How to do so ??

The one i tried to fade In s

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         var _selectedLinkEl = null;
         var _detailEl = null;
         var body = jQuery("body");
         var elem=null;

        jQuery(".user-link").mouseover(function(event) {
               _selectedLinkEl = this;
               _detailEl=jQuery(event.target).parent().next();
               _detailEl.fadeIn("slow");
                elem=jQuery(this).parent().next();
               _href=jQuery(this).attr('href').split("/")[2];

                jQuery.post('/users/user_detail/?name='+_href,
                 function(data){

                          elem.html(data).fadeIn("slow");
                 });//post

             body.mouseover(_bodyMouseOverFunction);
   }); // user-link

      var _bodyMouseOverFunction = function(event) {

          // to add some conditions here

             _detailEl.fadeOut("slow");
            body.unbind("mouseover", _bodyMouseOverFunction);



          };// mouseover

      });// doc ready
```

I need to write some conditions inside the _bodyMouseOverFunction but dont know how to specify .. 
Please give suggestions

Comment: Reading poorly indented code is difficult and frustrating, making it less likely that you'll get help from anyone.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos -- Indented ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [fadeout in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333713/fadeout-in-jquery)

Comment: It's better but still terrible, frankly. Why is the user-link not indented further? Why is `body.mouseover(_bodyMouseOverFunction);` indented differently to every other line in the same block (likewise for several lines throughout the code)? Why is the closing `}` for `_bodyMouseOverFunction` commented with `// mouseover` (which confuses it with another line further up that actually calls `mouseover`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `.mouseleave()` event on li instead of `_bodyMouseOverFunction` function, e.g.

```
jQuery("li").mouseleave(function(e1){
    jQuery("div",jQuery(this)).fadeOut("slow");         
}); // user-link
```

whenever user moves out either of link of content div, content div will hide automatically.

[`working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/qDywm/)

Comment: the thing i am getting fade out all the times even i try to hover on the div ....

Comment: i wrote a condition not to fade out when hover on the link .if(event.target = _selectedEl){//fadeout}

Comment: But dono how to add the condition to stay the div when hover on the Div or on any child elements of the div ....

Comment: THanks yaar i m done now with the mouseleave function .. Thanks a lot